# Declare a global type in an inner namespace

Tags: c++

I'm the owner of the [libzip++](https://bitbucket.org/markand/libzip) wrapper, a basic header around the C [libzip](https://nih.at/libzip/) library.

I declare a libzip namespace that mostly wraps the C functions and rename types to remove the zip_ prefix.

The C library defines a struct named `struct zip_stat`. I try to declare a typedef in the libzip namespace like this:

```
namespace libzip {

using Stat = struct zip_stat;

}
```

On GCC and clang, there is no problem and I can use libzip::Stat as an alias of struct zip_stat. On Visual Studio, I get an error saying that I try to use an undefined libzip::zip_stat structure, probably because this alias definition tries to resolve to a libzip::zip_stat structure.

On Visual Studio, this declaration is working, but not on gcc (which says that this does not declare anything)

```
namespace libzip {

using Stat = struct ::zip_stat;

}
```

Which compiler has the correct behaviour? And what declaration should I use?

EDIT: I've discovered that there is also a zip_stat function that may conflict with the structure.

Comment: Does removing the unnecessary `struct` help? `using Stat = zip_stat;`

Comment: I edited my question, there is a zip_stat function in the C library, that is probably the problem.

Comment: Any reason why you donot want to typedef ?

Comment: Because aliases are the "modern" version of typedef. But until I find a solution, I'll use it.